# Bootstrap modal not closing on form submit - Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have this modal in my view:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="addListItem" tableindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addListItem" aria-hidden="true">
  ......
  ......
      <div class="modal-body">
         <%= form_for @list_item, :remote => true, :html => {:id => "addForm"} do |f| %>
             <%= f.hidden_field :upc, :value => @item.upc %>
             <%= f.hidden_field :inventory_item_id, :id => "inventoryID", :value => "" %>
             <%= f.submit("Add It!", class: "btn", :id => "addSubmit") %>
         <% end %>
      </div>
  ......
  ......
</div>
```

Because the form is remote, I want this modal to hide on form submit. Here's how I do that:

```
$('#addForm').submit(function() {
    $('#addListItem').modal('hide');
});
```

What's currently happening is puzzling me. When I hit submit, the form submits remotely and the modal stays open. When I hit the submit button a second time, the form submits again and the modal hides. Why is this modal not hiding on the first submit? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've had a similar problem before, and the way I solved this was by adding a click event to the submit button:

```
$('#addSubmit').click ->
   $('#addListItem').modal('hide');
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is so puzzling. This should work. I can run the second line in the console and the modal hides, but the click doesn't trigger it.

Comment: Well, I might be an idiot. This works now, guessing because I restarted my server? Strange. Nice answer though, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`$(modal).on("click", 'input[type="submit"]', (e) ->
  modal.modal('hide')`

Comment: Of course substitute the selector of the outermost div belonging to the modal for `modal`