# Hide Bootstrap modal with fade out effect using Javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a basic bootstrap modal to log in, which doesn't close itself when I hit submit. I solved it using [this simple jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23615549/bootstrap-modal-not-closing-on-form-submit-rails):

```
$('#myModal').modal('hide');
```

But I also want the modal to fade out properly using bootstrap's fade class - which currently doesn't happen, it instantly gets hidden.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

```js
$('#myModal').delay(1000).fadeOut(450);

 setTimeout(function(){
    $('#myModal').modal("hide");
 }, 1500);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can pass the duration of the fade effect to the fadeout function. then pass a callback function as a second parameter. In the body of the callback function, you then hide the modal window

```
   $('#myModal').fadeOut(500,function(){
                $('#myModal').modal('hide');
             });
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the HTML of your modal has the `.fade` class, Bootstrap will do the rest, [per their documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-remove-animation):

```
<div class="modal fade">
  Modal content here
</div>
```

If you are still having trouble, you'll have to post more of your code.

Answer (score 2):

use jQuery :

```
$('#myModal').fadeOut();
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Comment: I think it's pretty obvious that $.fadeOut() just fades out the $element, it doesn't need explanation.

Comment: using jQuery fadeOut() isn't working now with Bootstrap 4 - the black overylay remains...

Answer (score 1):

This work for me:

```
$("#id").attr("data-dismiss","modal");
```