# Multiple modals on with same element name on same page

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make it so when a user clicks outside of a modal, it closes it. So far, it only works on the first modal, and not the second.

Here is my code:

```
$(window).click(function(e){
    $('.reportModal').each(function(){
        var modal = $(this);
        if (e.target == modal) {
            $('.reportModal').fadeOut();
        }
    });
    //if (e.target == $('.reportModal')[0] || e.target == ) {
    //    $('.reportModal').fadeOut();
    //}
});
```

I want to make it so it is effective on all of them. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when a user clicks outside of a modal, it closes it.

So... This can also be explained this way:

If the user click on an element which has no parent having the modal class...

Now you have the click to open the modal should be "delayed" a little with the `:visible"` condition.

Here is a quick made demo:

```js
$("button.open").on("click", function() {
  let modal = $("." + $(this).data("target"))
  setTimeout(function() {
    modal.fadeIn();
  }, 200)
})


$(document).on("click", function(e) {

  if ($(".reportModal").is(":visible") && $(e.target).closest(".reportModal").length === 0) {
    $(".reportModal").fadeOut(); // Whichever the opened one is... Close them all!
  }
});
```

```css
.reportModal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 30%;
  left: 45%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="reportModal one">
  <div>My custom modal #1</div>
</div>
<button class="open" data-target="one">open modal #1</button>

<div class="reportModal two">
  <div>My custom modal #2</div>
</div>
<button class="open" data-target="two">open modal #2</button>
```

Comment: Thank you! Though I had to alter the code to length === 1 because that would mean 1 is open right?

Comment: no.. if the `length` is 1 in the condition above, the user clicked inside a modal because `$(e.target)` is a child of a `.reportModal`.

Comment: I tried the code but it triggers the modal fade in fade out

Comment: The proper way to close a modal is `.modal("hide")`. If you want a fade effect, [here is another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39166782/2159528)

Comment: I decided to just use an answer I will provide

Comment: The code you provided worked because it closed out both -- but when I click inside the modal it goes away as well, although I had to put === 1. I'm also not using the bootstrap version

Comment: Ho!... I really assumed BootStrap!

Comment: I edited with better... Because if `e.target` is a button inside the modal, your solution will close the modal.

Comment: I don't understand why the second part of the code doesn't work on mine but works in the demo

Comment: so in the end I had to target something apart of the reportModal and that was the reportModalContent in the closest('.reportModalContent').length == 0

Answer (score 0):

Since it only has two modals, I decided to grab the element by it's array position:

```
$(window).click(function(e){
    if (e.target == $('.reportModal')[0] || e.target == $('.reportModal')[1]) {
        $('.reportModal').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Comment: Maybe you test an empty modal... Try with a button that should not close it inside ;) Or with a simple `div` inside...